# Handling Non-NULL Database Columns With NULL Values

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to update my database columns that are not null but I only want some of them to be updated. The rest of them should be old values. How can I handle this problem using a SQL Server stored procedure.

Comment: Can you give any example of your problem? I don't understand what's your problem exactly

Comment: @Kamran, you should edit your original question to include more of that information, otherwise  you're going to get a bunch of downvotes.

Comment: @Kamran I don't think a stored proc is needed for your situation.

Answer (score 2):

The basic syntax to do a conditional `update` where you want to exclude certain non-null values would be something like this:

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.col2 = update_value
FROM table1 t1
WHERE t1.col1 IS NOT NULL
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM table1
        WHERE t1.id = t2.id
            AND t.col1 IN ('value1','value2') --values you don't want to update
                    );
```

If you have a fewer values that needs to be updated rather than the ones you don't need to update, you can simply do this instead:

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.col2 = update_value
FROM table1 t1
WHERE t1.col1 IS NOT NULL
 AND t.col1 IN ('value1','value2'); --values you want to update
```